# how to add image-processing matlab libraries to keil

Tags: matlab, image-processing, keil

I am working with A robot 
 
I want to work with The Image processing of the robot, and I programme the ARM 
with Keil And Kiel is in C language, and I do Image processing with Matlab, how can I add the Libraries to Keil?

Comment: Have you considered using a C language image processing tool?

Comment: @AnderBiguri I think Its easier to Do image processing with Matlab  IS there Any way to use Matlab codes in Keil ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure whether this will work in Keil, but from Matlab, you can [generate normal C code](https://www.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/the-joy-of-generating-c-code-from-matlab.html). Not all MATLAB code can be converted to C, you most likely need to alter your code before it is ready for conversion into C.

Comment: Doesn't look like you need any further libraries. Please refer here: https://www.mathworks.com/products/matlab-coder/features.html#run-anywhere . I have only used this for simple code and not for complicated algorithms. So if you use multiple toolboxes etc., I am not sure this would work. Look here for another Demo: https://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2011/11/14/generating-c-code-from-your-matlab-algorithms/